# How to make Unity gravity and AddForce accelerate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a clone of Hollow Knight, and my character is falling at a constant rate instead of accelerating. I tried changing the gravity scale and using Addforce instead of rigidbody gravity.

This is the code I tried for the gravity

```
public Rigidbody2D rb;
void FixedUpdate(){
    rb.AddForce(-transform.up*100f * Time.fixedDeltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: It’s not necessary to do gravity in code.

Comment: It was going at a constant rate, as I said in the question

Comment: Terminal velocity is a thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a lot of testing and it doesn't seem like what you say is true.
In a new project, I simply created a rigidbody2D gameobject and added this script to it.

```
public void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(PrintDistance());
}

IEnumerator PrintDistance()
{
    float p = 0;
    for (; ; )
    {
        p = transform.position.y;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        print("Distance per second: " + (transform.position.y - p));
    }
}
```

As you can see from the console, every second, the distance traveled increases, so the speed is not constant but accelerated.
How can you see that the falling speed is not constant?
Try adding this script and tell me the results.
I can speculate that some other part of your project is causing this problem, or you have changed some properties in the Physics panel in Project Settings, but that is not likely.

**if you think my answer helped you, you can mark it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). I would very much appreciate it :)**

Comment: It says -6 or around that (like 5.9999947 kinda thing) every time

Comment: What is the value of Max translation speed in Project Settings > Physics2D?

Comment: What are the values of your Rigidbody2D? Are there other components? Which?

Comment: It's 100 so yeah

Comment: It's 1000 mass but that should be fine, 0 drag. 10 gravity scale. I also have a movement script

Comment: So my movement is causing it when I do rb.MovePosition(rb.position+moveDirection*moveSpeed*Time.fixedDeltaTime); but IDK how to fix that

Comment: What is the started position of the player? Probably if you are using the Move () method at every frame, the object cannot fall because you always tell it to stay in a precise position. Can you add the code where you call the Move () method to the question? What is moveDirection and where is it changed?

Comment: The MovePosition is in FixedUpdate
    void FixedUpdate(){
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position+new Vector2(moveDirection, 0f)*moveSpeed*Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    } 
 and moveDirection is changed in update

Comment: Unfortunately your script cannot work for the reason written in the previous comment. I advise you not to use Move (), but to try to move the player with AddForce (). If I was helpful, please mark the question as accepted if you want :)